# Cannot Run Because of Uninitialized local variable Error

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int calc(int m, int c, int d_T) {
    int Q = m * c * d_T;
    return Q;
}

int main(){
    cout << "Enter mass/c/and delta temperature" << endl;
    int val, val1, val2;
    cin >> val, val1, val2;
    int Q = calc(val, val1, val2);
    cout << Q << endl;
}
```

I doesn't let me run because of these errors please help!:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4700   uninitialized local variable 'val2' used    arduino
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4700   uninitialized local variable 'val1' used    arduino

But I initialized the variables?

Comment: What if you write it like: `int val = 0, val1 = 0, val2 = 0;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
cin >> val >> val1 >> val2;
```

Comment: sorry my fault i forgot that :)